# mvc+angular not getting response of post method in tablet

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, tablet

The application is in mvc+angular js.
From the login page application user is taken to the dashboard page.
The login post action works on the desktop but it is not working on the tablet. If I inspect the tablet with remote debugging, I can not find any errors and the response is empty.

Please help me on that.

```
Request URL:example.com/Account/Login
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Found
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:248
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host:180.211.114.147:97
Origin:example.com
Referer:example.com/Account/Login
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.0.4; GT-P7310 Build/IMM76D) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.166 Safari/537.36
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
__RequestVerificationToken:64n4kAk06a1PWABGIXLpE2Tnm1v7_1rC6cCIopLeCdNF_1Q3xcir7pJUA0_y378SJxpMQ2fg_cPynE5acHanepnJ9yssLIa0I-Htuehw1pGDTDk0TC2Prhn4ph51qun0uzgHdvWXTrgtPVrGTSiQU_k_FGj9srDjc23tdKv54wc1
UserName:abc
Password:abc
RememberMe:False
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:private
Content-Length:118
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 26 Feb 2016 10:49:56 GMT
Location:/
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Set-Cookie:.sessionVRSSPL=k1a2ahcdo0f2jdusojoyrlbn; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie:.vrssplUsernameCookie=; expires=Thu, 25-Feb-2016 10:49:52 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie:.formVRSSPL=6892A40852C4C0CB194DEC4DE37746BC204A3FF36DF8A06B03B9C05BA3EB30F0BF51ADE8BA0A016E18E03BA6C80DD920ED8EB4FCCFEEA0D4229077F9925729A0084DC57F445F1894298725C9E480A273931DCF1F20539E46C9140FEA5E0B2682B8B164EEC08B8C714D540A37AE16D3D36548B107021C43C718578F982A543511; path=/; HttpOnly
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version:4.0
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET``
```

Comment: Below is my code<input id="btnLogin" type="submit" class="btn btn-wide btn-success col-xs-offset-6" style="width: 85px; font-weight: bold; margin-left: 0px" value="Sign In">


Below is the method of controller.

  public ActionResult Login(Login login)
{
     //if valid user
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}

Comment: Could you paste the angularjs code that handles the login post action?

Comment: on button click post method of button is called that is action method of Account controller is called.

Comment: public ActionResult Login(Login login)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Empty";
           ///Here logic goes for session and wrong attemp and cookies
     //if valid user
     
     return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            //var data = new { success = success, Message = Message.ToString() };
            //return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);   
            return View();
        }